# If $R$ and $S$ are both rings given, then $R\times \{0_S\}\simeq R$

Tags: abstract-algebra

If $R$ and $S$ are both rings given, then $R\times \{0_S\}\simeq R$

I know how to write ring homomorphism and isomorphisms but in this case we have 2 ring,

Is something like $f(x,y)=x$ projection map enogh? I feels like some clarifications are neccessary? Can you give me hint?

Comment: If you know the concept of ring isomorphisms, then why don‘t you just check that your proposed map is an isomorphism. (It is. And there aren‘t many choices for $y$.)

Comment: can you think of a better and more natural isomorphism?

Comment: What can be more natural than this?!

Comment: The isomorphisms are exactly the following: Let $f: R \to R$ be an isomorphism, then $f \times 0$ is an isomorphism. In particular, $f = \mathrm{id}$ works and sometimes can be the only candidate.